# How to load SVMlight format files in compressed form to pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, svmlight

I have data in SVMlight format (label feature1:value1 feature2:v2 ...) as such

```
talk.politics.guns a:12 about:1 abrams:1 absolutely:1
talk.politics.mideast I:4 run:10 go:3
```

I tried `sklearn.load_svmlight_file` but it doesn't seem to work with categorical string features and labels. I am trying to store it into pandas DataFrame. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Your SVMLight file does not have the correct format. Read more about the format here: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/svm_light/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by hand...
One way you can convert the file you want in a DataFrame:

```py
svmformat_file = """~/svmformat_file_sample"""

# Read to list
with open(svmformat_file, mode="r") as fp:
    svmformat_list = fp.readlines()

# For each line we save the key:values to a dict
pandas_list = []
for line in svmformat_list:
    line_dict = dict()

    line_split = line.split(' ')
    line_dict["label"] = line_split[0]

    for col in line_split[1:]:
        col = col.rstrip()  # Remove '\n'
        col_split = col.split(':')
        key, value = col_split[0], col_split[1]
        line_dict[key] = value

    pandas_list.append(line_dict)
```

The result DataFrame with your example file:

```
pd.DataFrame(pandas_list)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out that the accepted answer from Christian Gomes will fail if one of your words is `'label'`, because you'll overwrite the classification label with the count of the word in the vector. Also, because the count wasn't converted to an `int`, you can't do any math.

Since you know for certain that each (feature, value) pair is separated by a `:`, you could get around this by making your `'label'` key something like `':label'`. It's not ideal, but it will avoid the collision.

Alternatively, you could store the labels in a separate dataframe, which is probably a better solution, since you probably don't want to do math on your classification labels.

```py
svmformat_file = """~/svmformat_file_sample"""

# Read to list
with open(svmformat_file, mode="r") as fp:
    svmformat_list = fp.read().splitlines()

# For each line we save the key:values to a dict
pandas_label_list = []
pandas_feature_list = []
for line in svmformat_list:
    feature_dict = {}

    items = line.split()
    pandas_label_list.append({'label': items[0]})

    for pair in items[1:]:
        feature_name, count = pair.split(':')
        feature_dict[feature_name] = int(count)

    pandas_feature_list.append(feature_dict)
```

Then, using the same data Christian used, you now have two dataframes:

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame(pandas_label_list)
>>>                 label
0   talk.politics.guns
1   talk.politics.mideast
>>> pd.DataFrame(pandas_feature_list)
>>> a about abrams absolutely   I run  go
0  12     1      1          1 NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN   NaN    NaN        NaN   4  10   3
```